# Diagnosing and improving computation speed

Tags: python, c++, performance, numpy, tetgen

I have a script that imports a module `geometry`, and this module slows down my script to an extreme level. My script generates a bitmap and **for 16 million pixels it would take 100+ hours**

here the problematic module:

```
'''
Created on 2 fevr. 2014

@author: gary
'''
#module name is: geometry.py

import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import tetgen

def barycentric_coords(vertices, point):
    T = (np.array(vertices[:-1])-vertices[-1]).T
    v = np.dot(la.inv(T), np.array(point)-vertices[-1])
    v.resize(len(vertices))
    v[-1] = 1-v.sum()
    #print vertices
    return v

def tetgen_of_hull(points):
    tg_all = tetgen.TetGen(points)

    hull_i = set().union(*tg_all.hull)
    hull_points = [points[i] for i in hull_i]

    tg_hull = tetgen.TetGen(hull_points)
    return tg_hull, hull_i

def containing_tet(tg, point):
    for tet in tg.tets:
        verts = [tg.points[j] for j in tet]
        bcoords = barycentric_coords(verts, point)
        if (bcoords >= 0).all():
            return bcoords
    return None, None
```

this is the stats cProfile gives on my script that uses the functions above, obviously that's where time's spent:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1291716   45.576    0.000  171.672    0.000 geometry.py:10(barycentric_coords)

  6460649   31.617    0.000   31.617    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
  2583432   15.979    0.000   15.979    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc'
objects}
     2031   12.032    0.006  193.333    0.095 geometry.py:26(containing_tet)
  1291716   10.944    0.000   58.323    0.000 linalg.py:244(solve)
  1291716    7.075    0.000    7.075    0.000 {numpy.linalg.lapack_lite.dgesv}
  1291716    5.750    0.000    9.865    0.000 linalg.py:99(_commonType)
  2583432    5.659    0.000    5.659    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray._fastCopyAn
dTranspose}
  1291716    5.526    0.000    7.299    0.000 twodim_base.py:169(eye)
  1291716    5.492    0.000   12.791    0.000 numeric.py:1884(identity)
```

So here's my question:

`numpy` seems to be quite slow at handling the calculation of barycentric coordinates here, would it be worth it to do it in `c++`? Or would there be any way to optimize this in another way (in python) ?

Comment: @VladimirF sorry I mistakenly clicked 'post' before finishing...

Comment: You're spending a lot of time converting python lists to numpy arrays. Is there any way you can build those as numpy arrays immediately instead? (Not too familiar with numpy, so I'm probably talking out of my receding hairline...)

Comment: Would it by any chance be possible to remove any numpy from here and run it via pypy?

Comment: @molbdnilo you are right, if he pushes the for-loop down to numpy level, it should speed up a lot

Comment: You'll probably find that [`line_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/) gives a much more helpful output than `cProfile`

Answer (score 1):

The real time-sink is likely to be the matrix inversion you do in `barycentric_coords`:

```
    v = np.dot(la.inv(T), np.array(point)-vertices[-1])
```

Remember, in pretty much all cases: [Don't invert that matrix!](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/)

You can replace that line with:

```
v = np.linalg.lstsq(T, np.array(point)-vertices[-1])[0]
```

To get the same result with a much faster least-squares solution.